# Biweekly (every two weeks) cron expression interpreted by Cronos library

Tags: c#, .net, cron

I need a biweekly cron expression to be interpreted by [Cronos nuget package](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos) in C#.

By biweekly I mean something like this: Every 2 weeks on Monday.

I tried several expressions, but nothing seems to work.
One expression that I tried is this one:

```
0 0 * * 1/2
```

and this is my code to test the expression:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

// Convert the cron expression to a CronExpression instance
var cron = CronExpression.Parse("0 0 * * 1/2");

// Get the next occurrences
var nextOccurrence = cron.GetNextOccurrence(startDate);
var nextOccurrence2 = cron.GetNextOccurrence(nextOccurrence.Value);
var nextOccurrence3 = cron.GetNextOccurrence(nextOccurrence2.Value);
var nextOccurrence4 = cron.GetNextOccurrence(nextOccurrence3.Value);
```

And the result, for the cron expression 0 0 * * 1/2 is:

```
nextOccurrence.Value.ToString()
"8/2/2023 12:00:00 AM"
nextOccurrence2.Value.ToString()
"8/4/2023 12:00:00 AM"
nextOccurrence3.Value.ToString()
"8/6/2023 12:00:00 AM"
nextOccurrence4.Value.ToString()
"8/7/2023 12:00:00 AM"
```

Could someone help me find a biweekly cron expression?

Comment: `0 0 1 21/14 8/1 ? 2023/1` every 14 days starting next monday at 01:00 AM

Comment: Cronos seems to not understand that. Does Cronos only support a Subset of the cron syntax?

Comment: This is not a cron expression recognized by Cronos library. When it tries to parse it, I get the following error: Cronos.CronFormatException: 'Months: Value must be a number between 1 and 12 (all inclusive).'

Comment: Here is the documentation of Cronos https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos
It contains also the supported format

Comment: `0 0 0 ? * 2/14 *` ought to be every 14 days starting Monday.

Comment: @MichaelFoster this is not recognized by Cronos:  Cronos.CronFormatException: 'Days of month: Value must be a number between 1 and 31 (all inclusive).'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with a simple cron expression, the better you can do is select one day on first week and another day in the middle of the month:

```
using Cronos;

DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

// Convert the cron expression to a CronExpression instance
var cron = CronExpression.Parse("0 0 1-6,15-20 * 1");

// next year's ocurrences
var nextOccurrence = cron.GetNextOccurrence(startDate);
Console.WriteLine(nextOccurrence);
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    nextOccurrence = cron.GetNextOccurrence(nextOccurrence.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(nextOccurrence);
}
```

Output:

```
9/4/2023 12:00:00 AM
9/18/2023 12:00:00 AM
10/2/2023 12:00:00 AM
10/16/2023 12:00:00 AM
11/6/2023 12:00:00 AM
11/20/2023 12:00:00 AM
12/4/2023 12:00:00 AM
12/18/2023 12:00:00 AM
1/1/2024 12:00:00 AM
1/15/2024 12:00:00 AM
2/5/2024 12:00:00 AM
2/19/2024 12:00:00 AM
```

You have to use another tool for what you want.